# rewrite rule php to non php not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a read alot and this seems to be correct as to what i understand.
I tried several different examples and scenarios, but it doesn't seem to work

I want to remove .php from these 2 files, and i am trying the below, but cannot figure out what's wrong,
any ideas please?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^404\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^recover-password\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /recover-password/ [L,R=301]
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` cannot match your URL, it just matches host name part of URL.

Change your rules to this in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(recover-password|404)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(recover-password|404)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```